# MonoDeveloper + MonoTouch - Image refresh

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Using MonoDevelop 2.6.1 and MonoTouch 4.x

When an image is changed in the project which is set as "content", the image is not refreshed when the app is rebuilt. This happens even if the MonoDevelop "**Clean**" command is used.

The only way to get an image updated is to delete the **bin** and **obj** folders and then delete the app on the simulator.

Is there a better way to have new images and files marked as "content" in general updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug with the way the app updated the images inside the .app file. Could you submit a bug on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ so we can get this is looked into and fixed - if you could provide a simple test case then that would be perfect.

Thanks,

ChrisNTR